# Feeds from several sites

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RSS feed of your favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags)
>   [Is there a way to see questions with a certain tag from all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101905/is-there-a-way-to-see-questions-with-a-certain-tag-from-all-stack-exchange-sites)

I am a programmer and wanted to know if there was a way to have a feed that incorporates several sites like stackoverflow, game development, programmers etc. Mainly I get tired of keeping multiple tabs open and switching back and forth and wanting to know if there is a better way I am missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set up your own filter on https://stackexchange.com/filters