# How do you filter twice by tag?

Tags: support, tags

If you go to 'tags' and click a tag, you get questions filtered by that tag.

How can you refine the filter with another tag (without having to type the tag name into the search bar)?

Clicking another tag from inside the search results resets the filter.

Found the answer - in the sidebar on the right is 'related tags'. Click on one of these and you get a double tag search.

Comment: I have changed the tag from [tag:feature-request] to [tag:support]. If you really want to be this a [tag:feature-request] you must provide a concrete proposal how this should be solved UI wise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Filters release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/282094) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101905/282094

Comment: @Rob; custom filters do the same job, but are a bit much for a casual browse, where I do not know which tags I might want to refine a search with.

Comment: JMP, it's true that searching overall, and using tags specifically, could be improved. I try to do a few searches and see which tags are more frequent, to see if a quick answer could be found using a tag. The *problem* with tags is that *if* the question isn't correctly tagged, or the information you seek is in the answer, adding tags to your search **eliminates** results that you may want to see but Googling with too many search terms may still return some results (and mention that a certain word is missing from *that* particular result). It's skill (art?) and science, adding luck is unfair.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to type *somewhere*. If you won't type into the search box, type into the filter dialog instead:

> [image]