# How to watch tags across more than one Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, tags, linux

How do users watch any given tag across multiple Stack Exchange sites?

For example, to watch `[bash]` or `[awk]` I watch the tag on Stack Overflow. However, it appears I must re-watch that same tag on, e.g. Unix & Linux, Super User, and so on. But any of those might have interesting questions and answers.

So it'd be nifty to have one tag apply across any Stack Exchange site. Might be a "Feature Request", so I tagged it as such.

UPDATE: [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101905/is-there-a-way-to-see-questions-with-a-certain-tag-from-all-stack-exchange-sites/110281#110281) (see comments)

Comment: Have you ever heard of [tag-filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-filters/info)? Not a well-known feature, but it sounds like it could do the job ...

Comment: @Glorfindel - the link is to a list of questions tagged with that tag - is there a specific question (or other location) that documents how this might be used for cross-site tagwatching, as the querent desires?

Comment: @Glorfindel I see - though I do not see on, e.g., my tags in Stack Overflow, how to filter them... hmm...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the tag wiki contains more information and where to find it. (I've updated the link). Brian, you have to manage your favorite tags on that location separately from your SO account.

Comment: @Glorfindel excellent update - [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101905/is-there-a-way-to-see-questions-with-a-certain-tag-from-all-stack-exchange-sites/110281#110281) is the same question worded differently. I added the globaltag-megablender - I suppose I'll figure it out soon...

Comment: ... I'm getting it - so if I go on Stack Exchange, I see the filter settings. To gather tags across all Stack Exchange sites, I must go to Stack Exchange to see those tags. If I am on Stack Overflow though, I will only see tags from Stack Overflow - which makes sense, now that I think of it. So I think I'll have to decide - camp out on Stack Overflow, or simply go to Stack Exchange above that - that sort of thing.